# Viability of Dysons bladeless fans?

Tags: pressure, air

Do Dyson's [bladeless fans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bladeless_fan) produce enough air pressure to cool say an air conditioning unit and do they produce a vortex pressure like a bladed fan?

Comment: More on Dyson fan: http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+Dyson+fan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't get too confused by the "bladeless fan" marketing babble.  Something, probably a traditional blower, is pushing air around inside the device.  This is ducted so that the flow blows in one direction from little nozzles on the inside of a ring.  That causes a lot more air to be moved by Bernoulli's principle.  Basically, the ring and nozzles converts high pressure low flow air into low pressure high flow air.

Overall, this system is likely to be (I don't have any numbers, just a guess on my part) less efficient than a traditional fan.  The claimed advantage is that you don't feel pulses as individual fan blades spin around.  I find that argument rather hard to swallow since I never noticed pulses from a traditional fan.  After a relatively short distance the flow will break up and become turbulent anyway, even if it started out perfectly smooth, so this whole issue smells strongly of marketing BS to me.

Comment: If you have ever seen a Dyson on display, working, you will find that the fan does produce significantly less turbulent air flow. Wither that is worth the $200 price tag is up to you. But yes, it IS a highly inefficient fan.